# $addToSet and upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

I know I can't use upsert and the positional operator together, but I am looking for away to append to array if some fields of the object I am inserting do not match some fields in an existing object within the array.

so if I have the existing document below, I would like to check for 'field' field's value and update/replace that subdocument if the fields match, and simply append to the array if they don't.

```
{
    myArray:[
         {
            field:'xyz'
         }       
    ]
}
```

Is there a good way to do this in node.js? I'm using the native driver.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do this in a single query. You can do this with two separate queries in the native driver. The first query would try to update the field in the array. If it doesn't find the document in the array that matches, it dispatches a second query to append the document to the array.

```
db.collection('coll').update({_id: _id, "myArray": {field: "xyz"}}, {"$set": {"myArray.$": {field: "xyzt"}}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, res) {
    if (err && err.code == 16836) { // no document was matched
        db.collection('coll').update({_id: _id}, {"$push": {myArray: {field: "xyzt"}}}, function(err, res) {
            console.log("Inserted document in array");
        }); 
    }
    console.log("Updated document in array");
});
```